# How to access the start and end index of a selected text from kivy textinput

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

That's my doubt.  How to access the first and last index of the selected text in kivy-TextInput. And also if possible can u tell me how to get the selected text.... I tried `TextInput.selection_text` but it just gives `''`. Nothing else.. Hope that no code or example is needed

Comment: You have to provide code example to show what you have tried.

Comment: Brother thanks for ur reply however i have figured it out myself by reading the docs.... Really thanks